# Youtube video stop on pause event

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I have several youtube iframes with TV channels on my website page.

```html
<div>
<iframe id="ytplayer"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ntBxGznOML0?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=0&controls=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div>
<iframe id="ytplayer"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zl4aeAfhdro?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=0&controls=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div>
<iframe id="ytplayer"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/URD4UWm-edg?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=0&controls=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div>
<iframe id="ytplayer"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/75j9l956bVs?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=0&controls=1&showinfo=0&loop=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use one java script to play video muted and to stop it on pause event but it doesnt work for me. The script is following

```js
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event){
     player.stopVideo(0);
         
  }
   

}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.mute();
    player.playVideo();
}
```

I need to full stop video on pause event, because it is live tv channel, so if I press pause now, in 10 minutes I will get a record but not a live stream. How can I make my script work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE

OP has multiple players and uses plain JavaScript, the following changes are:

1. Multiple players shared the same id, now each player has a unique id.
2. Added a `<button class='stop' data-id='yt*'>STOP</button>` for each player.

   - Each button has a `data-id`. It's value corresponds to it's player's id.
3. Wrapped `<section id='videoChannels'></section>` around everything.

   - Added the `eventListener` to `#videoChannels` so when a button is clicked `#videoChannels` is referred to as the `target.currentTarget` which can be compared to the `event.target` to determine the button that was clicked (i.e. `event.target`).
   - After the `capture eventPhase` the event chain reaches `event.target` (the button that was clicked) and the function `ytCommand()` is called on the player that corresponds to the button (see step 2.)

### Working Demo

<kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/mlf7COkx6yIbq4OshJdD/)</kbd>

---

## Stopping YouTube Player

1. Access the iframe by using [`contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) method
2. Next cross-domain communication through an iframe is possible with the [`postMessage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).
3. Next post commands from [YouTube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls)

### Relevant Code

```
$('#stop').on('click', function() {

  $('#ytPlayer')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});
```

### Working Demo

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/3fchv2Ld/)</kbd>

### Snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Stop YTPlayer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="videoChannels">
    <div>
      <iframe id="yt0" class="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8IzxdjVr5ZI?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <button class='stop' data-id='yt0'>STOP</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <iframe id="yt1" class="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AhenpCh6BO4?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <button class='stop' data-id='yt1'>STOP</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <iframe id="yt2" class="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HrmF-mPLybw?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <button class='stop' data-id='yt2'>STOP</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <iframe id="yt3" class="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6KouSwLP_2o?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <button class='stop' data-id='yt3'>STOP</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script>
    var vidCh = document.getElementById('videoChannels');

    vidCh.addEventListener('click', ytCommand, false);

    function ytCommand(event) {
      if (event.target != event.currentTarget) {
        var btn = event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        var ytp = document.getElementById(btn);
        ytp.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, but how can I use that script? I inserted it in my article, but it doesnt work.

Comment: My bad, you are using plain JavaScript, but upon further examination all of your iframes share the same id. One of the most fundamental rules in HTML is that you never assign an id to more than one element. You need to make each id unique. I suggest you add a number to the end of each id (ex. `ytPlayer1`, `ytPlayer2`, etc.). Of course in doing so, the rest of your script must change as well. I will provide instructions later, I must go back to work.

Comment: Ok Thank you. I will wait)

Comment: @Amonnn Ready for review, sir. Happy coding.